# Servlet - output image from array results in broken image

Tags: java, image, servlets, stream

What I want to do is to get image file from disk, resize it and use servlet to serve it to the client.

However, I am getting broken image icon instead of the resized image. I am completely lost as to what might be wrong. Maybe only part of the image is streamed? Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mortennobel.imagescaling.ResampleFilters;
import com.mortennobel.imagescaling.ResampleOp;

public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        String downloadPath = "/pathtofile";

        File file = new File(downloadPath);

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        ResampleOp resampleOp = new ResampleOp(100, 100);
        resampleOp.setFilter(ResampleFilters.getLanczos3Filter());
        image = resampleOp.filter(image, null);

        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] imageBytes = data.getData();

        response.setContentType(FileBusiness.getFileMimeType(file));
        response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
             OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream())
        {
            while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0)
            {
                out.write(buf, 0, count);
            }

            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Here `file` being the file image read from disk.

Comment: To begin with, you should always `flush` your outputStreams

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the question. This does not fix the problem, however.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Updated the question with working servlet code.

Comment: It is always best to include the imports for an SSCCE.  For example, is that [`com.mortennobel.imagescaling.ResampleFilters`](http://code.google.com/p/java-image-scaling/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/mortennobel/imagescaling/ResampleFilters.java?r=128) referred to in the code?